# Aborting upload request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html

I'm having an issue where I am trying to support cancelling file uploads. I would like to know what the best practice for determine whether an upload is cancellable. So how can you determine when the file has completed uploading, versus the server generating/returning a response? I understand this is possible by tracking the file progress in HTML5, but since I have to support IE9, I am running out of ideas.

The end result is if you attempt to cancel a file upload that is nearing being completely upload, and issue the abort request, you end up aborting the response and the file is happily sitting on the server.

I am using jquery to submit the request, and am cancelling via the abort() method. I see in the browser console that the request was successfully aborted.

Am I missing something trivial?

Comment: Have you considered using an upload widget?  Many of them have Flash fallbacks, which will help you gain feature parity in horrible browsers.

Comment: Looking to implement this without flash, if possible. Don't think it is though :(

Comment: I was going to recommend [Plupload](http://www.plupload.com/), as I've used it before and have had good luck with it.  You can give it a list of possible backends to try out, including HTML5, Silverlight and Flash.  Unfortunately it doesn't look like you can actually cancel any in-progress uploads, so it won't solve your specific problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP now has the ability to track the upload progress.  See ["Session Upload Progress"](http://php.net/manual/en/session.upload-progress.php).

Use this feature to write a short script: `checkUpload.php`, and use AJAX to return the status back to your IE9 page.

```
<?php
$_SESSION["upload_progress_123"] = array(
 "start_time" => 1234567890,   // The request time
 "content_length" => 57343257, // POST content length
 "bytes_processed" => 453489,  // Amount of bytes received and processed
 "done" => false,              // true when the POST handler has finished, successfully or not
 "files" => array(
  0 => array(
   "field_name" => "file1",       // Name of the <input/> field
   // The following 3 elements equals those in $_FILES
   "name" => "foo.avi",
   "tmp_name" => "/tmp/phpxxxxxx",
   "error" => 0,
   "done" => true,                // True when the POST handler has finished handling this file
   "start_time" => 1234567890,    // When this file has started to be processed
   "bytes_processed" => 57343250, // Number of bytes received and processed for this file
  ),
  // An other file, not finished uploading, in the same request
  1 => array(
   "field_name" => "file2",
   "name" => "bar.avi",
   "tmp_name" => NULL,
   "error" => 0,
   "done" => false,
   "start_time" => 1234567899,
   "bytes_processed" => 54554,
  ),
 )
);
```

Using PHP, it is also now possible to **cancel** the upload process.  From that same manual page referenced above, comes the following text:

> It is also possible to cancel the currently in-progress file upload, by setting the 
>   $_SESSION[$key]["cancel_upload"] key to TRUE. When uploading multiple files in the same 
>   request, this will only cancel the currently in-progress file upload, and pending file 
>   uploads, but will not remove successfully completed uploads. When an upload is cancelled like 
>   this, the error key in $_FILES array will be set to UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION.

The only thing not covered in the PHP documentation is how to get the total file size.  There is a very good review of this process here: ["PHP Master | Tracking Upload Progress"](http://phpmaster.com/tracking-upload-progress-with-php-and-javascript/)